# how to merge array in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

In Controller:

```
public function subscription(){
        $this->load->model('ar/LogSubscriptionAR');
        $sub = $this->LogSubscriptionAR->merge('admin_contact','category')->get()->result_array();
        $this->load->view('admin/log/subscription',compact('sub','sub'));
    }
```

I have 3 Object on the List view

I want to show Admin: John Doe if the admin-1  and

show all if category id 1 
show tour_package: Europe if category id 31
show flight: all if category id -1

```
<tr class="data-template">          
            <td data-name="type"></td>
            <td data-name="name"></td>
            <td data-name="category"></td>
            <td data-name="admin_contact_selector"></td>            
</tr>
```

Comment: make your question correct. I think u tried inserting an image

Answer (score 0):

if this is only single array entry then you can try this otherwise you have to apply loop for complete set of arrays

```
$result[] = $array1[0] + $array2[0];

// print_r($result );

it will give you output

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Alice
            [age] => 1
        )

)
```

---

**Another alternative would be to loop through the second results array and add the values to the first array.**

```
// Get products results as an array
$this->db->select('products.title,
                   products.description,
                   products.price,
                   products.stock');
$this->db->from('products');
$this->db->where('product_id', $id);
$product = $this->db->get()->result_array();

// Get product attributes as an array
$this->db->select('name, value');
$this->db->from('product_attributes');
$this->db->where('product_id', $id);
$product_attributes = $this->db->get()->result_array();

// Loop through the results
foreach($product_attributes as $attribute) {

     // Add results to original product array
     $product[$attribute['name']] = $attribute['value'];
}
```

This should produce an array like this:

```
    [title]       => Modest Swimsuit - Full body 
    [description] => UV +50 Protection - Chlorine Resistant - Water Resistant - Quick Drying - Maximum Breathe Ability- Sea Water Resistant 
    [price]       => 59.95 
    [stock]       => 20
    [Brand]       => Modestly Active Swimwear 
    [Colour]      => Black and Light Blue
    [size]        => small
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM food_items JOIN categories ON food_items.item_category=categories.category_id AND food_items.item_status='1'");
        $result = array();
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $value) {
            $result[] = array_merge($value,array("foo"=>"foo")); 
        }
    print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
        [id] => 1
        [item_id] => ITEM34
        [item_name] => 
        [item_type] => Regular
        [item_price] => 0
        [item_description] => 
        [item_qty] => 0
        [item_status] => 1
        [last_modified] => 22-07-2017 09:47:06am
        [foo] => foo
```

This worked for me fine!!!